# Composite C1 - rejecting google map link in page "'=' is an unexpected token"

Tags: c1-cms

I am trying to add this to a Google page in a composite C1 website:

```
<a target="de" href="https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Palace+of+Westminster%2C+London%2C+United+Kingdom&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x487604c474bc432b%3A0x799496ad795e0a2c!3m8!1m3!1d2105!2d-0.041008!3d51.580681!3m2!1i779!2i652!4f13.1!4m2!3d51.499503!4d-0.1243569">
```

But I get the following error when I try and save the page:

'=' is an unexpected token, the expected token is ';'.

The URL is valid - how can I save this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace & with (remove spaces here)  & a m p ;

We have a guide on writing correct XHTML in templates etc to avoid errors like this:

http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Writing-XHTML

(Please check the "No HTML Entities" section there)